# Calculating Version QR Codes

Tags: bit

How many total bits are sorted in the grid of a Version 4 QR code?

All I could find is that Version 4 is 33 rows by 33 columns. Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in "*33 rows by 33 columns*' you mean that there are 33 **pixels** in both directions, you would simply multiple those two numbers together, and then multiply the result by 8 (as there are 8 bits in a byte, and one byte per pixel).

As such, you're probably looking for `33 * 33 * 8`.

That would be `8712` bits.